# Probability and Random Processes

Tags: probability

Before launching three new cuisines, A,B,C,a popular restaurant in the Metropolitan Akron
area conducted a tasting survey with the assistant of 70 University of Akron students. The
ﬁndings are summarized as follows:
32 liked cuisine A
10 liked cuisine A and B
24 liked cuisine B
11 liked cuisine A and C
6 liked cuisine A and B and C
31 liked cuisine C
14 liked cuisine B and C
a) Draw a Venn diagram representing the above survey
b) If a participating University of Akron student is selected at random, what is the probability
that he or she disliked all three types of new cuisines?

Comment: Hello, have you made an attempt at the question? If you have, would you mind sharing your working?

Comment: Have you done any work here?  With what precisely can we help you?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it says to draw a Venn diagram, so draw a Venn diagram. On a sheet of paper, draw three ovals, so  that any two have a region in common, and all three have a region in common. Label the three ovals $A$, $B$, and $C$. Here oval $A$ stands for all the people who like $A$. Ovals $B$ and $C$ have similar meanings.

The part of the world that is *common** to $A$ and $B$ stands for the people who like both $A$ and $B$, and so on.

The part of the world that is common to all of ovals $A$, $B$, and $C$ stands for the people who like *all* of $A$, $B$, and $C$. finally, the part of the world which is outside *all* the ovals stands for the people who don't like anything.

Altogether, the sheet of paper has $70$ people on it.

Now we will work **outwards**. We are told that $6$ liked $A$, $B$, and $C$. Write a $6$ in the little region which is common to all of ovals $A$, $B$ and $C$.

We are told that $10$ liked $A$ and $B$. This *includes* the $6$ people who liked everything. So $4$ people like $A$ and $B$, but don't like $C$. Put a $4$ in the little region which is common to $A$ and $B$, but is *outside* $C$.

We are told that $14$ liked $B$ and $C$. This includes the $6$ people who like everything. so there are $8$ people who like $B$ and $C$, but don't like $A$. write $8$ in the region which is common to $B$ and $C$, but outside $A$.

We are told that $11$ liked $A$ and $C$. This includes the $6$ people who like everything. so there are $5$ people who like $A$ and $C$, but don't like $B$. write $5$ in the region which is common to $A$ and $C$, but outside $B$.

Now we are told that $32$ liked $A$. Look at oval $A$. Parts of it have numbers already written in them. They are $6$ for the people who like everything, the $4$ who like $A$ and $B$ but not $C$, and the $5$ who like $A$ and $C$ but not $B$. The rest of $A$ consists of the people who only like $A$. There ae $32-(6+4+5)$ of them. So $17$ only like $A$. Write $17$ in the appropriate region of $A$.

Do the same for the people ho only like $B$, and the people who only like $C$.

Lots of numbers! Add them up. You might find a quickie way to do this, or else you can do it the painful slow way. There are $7$ numbers to add up.

Finally, whatever that sum is, the rest of the $70$ don't like anything. Write the number of people who like nothing in the "outside" region.

Now we know everything, and can answer any question. for the probability that a randomly chosen person likes nothing, divide the number of people in the outside region by $70$.